# Validate one field based on other in ektron html form?

Tags: c#, ektron

Am working on Ektron 9.I have created an ektron html form with n number of fields.
Suppose i have a radio button list(Choice Field) following a text field.My choice radio button list has 
two values Yes and No and the end user select one of those values.

I need to make the following text field required if the user select **Yes** in the choice radio button list.If selected **No** no need to make the text field required.

Is there any way to achieve the same by ektron custom validation?i have tried that but when am checking the fields the choice field not listing in the the insert field part of validation tab.

Is anything wrong with me ,if not anyone suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

Custom validation like you describe is not possible with standard Ektron HTML forms.  Your best bet would be to create an ASPX web form to achieve what you need.

There is the possibility of creating the HTML form, displaying it on an ASPX page and then adding your own custom javascript.  However this is error prone as the HTML form and JS are very closely tied together.  You are better off using an ASPX web form, and not an Ektron HTML form for this.

Comment: Interesting to be marked down and yet whoever did it has no better answer